# JavaScript Prototype.js replacement

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Hey guys I am working on converting some apps from JSP to JSF 2 and I have come to point in which we are displaying a google map. The old app used prototypes to get the proper data. We no longer support prototypes.

I am trying to replace

```
out.append("var index = 0; var count = markers.inject(0, function(acc, marker) { var count = marker.clusterCount ? marker.clusterCount : 1; return acc + count; });");
```

with

```
out.append("var index = 0; var count = markers.push(" +
                        "function(acc, marker) { " +
                            "var count = 0;" +
                            "count = marker.clusterCount ? marker.clusterCount : 1;" +
                            "return acc + count; " +
                        "}" +
                    ");");
```

This is from a class the builds javascript. I know I need a loop in here, as to where nothing works. Putting the loop in my function changes no values, wrapping the function in a loop breaks the map. With this I get partial results but I am missing a lot.

I have found the prototype and its source code here: http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Enumerable/prototype/inject/

Although it is helpful my lack of understanding of javascript is proving problematic. If anyone can help I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you replaced Prototype's [`.inject`](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Enumerable/prototype/inject/) with a call to [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). From their docs you can see that they are doing completely different things!

The native equivalent to `inject` is the [`.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Use

```
out.append("var index = 0; var count = markers.reduce(function(acc, marker) { var count = marker.clusterCount ? marker.clusterCount : 1; return acc + count; }, 0);");
```

Notice that you can also shorten `var count = marker.clusterCount ? marker.clusterCount : 1; return acc + count;` to `return acc + (marker.clusterCount || 1);`.

Comment: I will try this Monday morning. I didn't know about reduce. Thanks